# Where do Symfony2 shared CSS and JS assets go, best practice wise?

Tags: symfony

I normally place my JS and CSS Assetic assets inside a DefaultBundle, but I suppose the best place to put them would be in the app/Resources/public/(js|css) folders.

Also, to reference assets we use:

```
{% javascripts filter="" output="js/core.js" debug=true
    "@DefaultBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-1.6.2.js" %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

How do I go about referencing shared assets like jQuery and my CSS reset stylesheets in app/Resources/public/...?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes it's a good choice to not put libraries inside a Bundle

see here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html#vendors

> A bundle should not embed third-party libraries written in JavaScript, CSS, or any other language.

---

What i suggest you, is to put you jquery and reset files under something like: `app/Resources/public/js/jquery.min.js` and to change your code with something like:

```
{% javascripts filter="" output="js/core.js" debug=true
    "../app/Resources/public/js/jquery-1.6.2.js" %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

I hope this will work for you.

**EDIT**: Edited answer to be like https://stackoverflow.com/a/9237004/505836, thanks David.

Comment: I would prefer having the scripts in a non-public folder, but this is helpful, thanks for answering.

Comment: It's useless to put a javascript file in a non public folder because this file will be download by the client browser and then will be public ;)

Comment: No no no, that is not the way to go with assetic! Assetic's purpose is to serve raw or compiled files in a production environment. If your JS file is not supposed to be directly accessible, don't put it in the web folder, it would be there twice (the raw file you've put and the assetic output). Instead, drop it to "app/Resources/public/js/jquery-1.6.2.js" and pass assetic this path.

Answer (score 27):

You could also use this:

```
{% stylesheets '../app/Resources/public/css/*' %}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Comment: This is much better than keeping things in a public folder and is what I've been scratching my head about all night! Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way I this could be extended to images in app/Resources/public/images?

Comment: I believe you can use {% image %} {% endimage %} blocks similarly to the {% stylesheets %} {% endstylesheets %}

Comment: This will load files alphabetically, but how to force load files in my own order?

Comment: You would probably need to specify each asset individually to control the order, you may be able to use special file naming to get a particular output order. This is fairly old post, I would suggest looking at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html for more current information. I would encourage folks to look at the named assets section as far as best practices and ease of management go.

Answer (score 8):

My solution is almost the same as David's, but using `%kernel.root_dir%` instead of hard-coding the `app` folder (although, I doubt many change this folder's name), e.g.:

```
{%- javascripts output='compiled/main.js'
    '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/public/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'
    '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/public/js/underscore-1.5.2.min.js'
    '@MyOwnBundle/Resources/public/js/default.js'
-%}
    <script src='{{ asset_url }}'></script>
{%- endjavascripts %}
```

If the third party libraries reference their own assets (e.g. typically images in a `img` sub-folder, referenced from .css files), it's usually sufficient to create the corresponding symlinks on the server, e.g. `ln -s .../app/Resources/public/img .../web/img` or something similar. Or use the cssrewrite filter, of course - but beware of its caveats.

(Also, note that I don't use the `type="<mime-type>"` attribute, as the files' content-type is supplied in the HTTP headers anyway.)

Comment: I like this answer the most.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace `../app/Resources/public/css/` by `public/css/`. The same for Javascript folder.

```
{% stylesheets filter='less' output='css/core' 'public/css/*' %}

      <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

{% endstylesheets %}

{% javascripts "public/js/*" %}

      <script src="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/javascript"></script>

{% endjavascripts %}
```

Here all the files of `/web/public` folder are automatically loaded.