# Symfony2 - How to reference files from the web directory with {% javascripts %} in twig?

Tags: symfony, assets, assetic

I'm using libraries like amcharts that have many js files.

I put amcharts in `web/js/amcharts` [as suggested julesbou](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903473/where-do-symfony2-shared-css-and-js-assets-go-best-practice-wise) and then

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% javascripts  '/js/amcharts/amcharts.js' %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

But I get `[exception] 500 | Internal Server Error | RuntimeException
[message] The source file &quot;/amcharts/amcharts.js&quot; does not exist.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

To include a file under `web` try removing the forward slash from your path i.e.

```
{% javascripts  'js/amcharts/amcharts.js' %}
                 ^ remove / here
```

Comment: the `asset()` function can be used instead of creating an asset collection with `javascripts` if you only reference a single css/js file. But keep in mind that the asset won't be processed by any filter this way. however it's not true that `javascripts` only accepts `@AcmeBundle` style paths.

Comment: @nifr I haven't been able to get `javascripts` to work with files under `web`. if it's possible, I actually prefer it

Comment: The `{% javascripts %}` tag does nothing more than configuring a new asset collection like adding a config directive `assetic.assets.<asset-name>.(inputs|filters|output)` does. it just returns the output-name as `asset_url` variable to twig with the correct current path. You can definitely add files from the `web` folder to an asset collection's input-array.

Comment: Further the **[documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html#vendors)** clearly states that it's **not** advised to put javascript/css libraries into bundles. `A bundle should not embed third-party libraries written in JavaScript, CSS, or any other language.
`

Comment: @nifr You're right! I was able to get it to work w/o the initial forward slash

Comment: jeah that's the point ... i was just about to post this as an answer. an absolute path as asset collection input doesn't point to `web` but the filesystem-root `/`. Now I'm too lazy - just edit your answer and we'll have this issue solved :)

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you have put your javascripts sources named xyz.js in 'js/' folder is source then you will have to fetch this javascripts via your "app/resources/base.html" file loke this :

```
{% block javascripts %}
     <script src="{{ asset('js/xyz.js') }}" type="text/javascript"> </script>
{% endblock %}
```

and when in remaining twig file you extends base.html.twig like below :

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %} 
  {% block display %}
  {% endblockdisplay %}
```

it automatically fetch your javascripts . Even if you want to modify the javascripts code for that particular child twig then you will have to write like as :

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %} 

    {% block display %}
     // Your display content here
    {% endblockdisplay %}

    {% block javascripts %}
       {{ parent() }}
        // Your changing code here
    {% endblockjavascripts %}
```