# Symfony 2.6 - Add jQuery file to Twig

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, twig, assetic

I'm a beginner developing a web app in Symfony2 and Twig for Google Chrome. I have read a lot of posts about how to add javascripts  to a twig file like these:

[Where do Symfony2 shared CSS and JS assets go, best practice wise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903473/where-do-symfony2-shared-css-and-js-assets-go-best-practice-wise)

[Including stylesheets and Javascript to Twig (Spanish article)](http://librosweb.es/libro/symfony_2_x/capitulo_7/incluyendo_hojas_de_estilo_y_javascript_en_twig.html)

[How to Use Assetic for Asset Management](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html)

And much more **stackoverflow** questions related to this issue (I'm risking to a lot of downvotes but simply I don't know what's wrong) but with all the documentation available I'm getting a 404 error when I enter to a webpage that tries to look for the jQuery file:

[image]

This is my current code (based from the first link I reference above):

```
    {% javascripts filter="" output="js/core.js" debug=true
        "../interemplea/Resources/public/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
```

This is my project structure:

[image]

**Notes:** I have tried to use assetics and this was the code (with no success):

```
{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Also I ran this command to create symlinks:

```
 php app/console assets:install web [--symlink]
```

Am I missing **some step** that is not mentioned in the links I read?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: have you run `assetic:dump`?

Comment: I tried to run but i got this exception C:\wamp\www\interemplea\app/../web/Resources/public/js/jqu  
  ery-1.11.3.min.js" does not exist. I have to mention I removed app_dev.php and app.php, could that be affecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% block javascripts %} <script src="{{ asset('bundles/interemplea/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script> {% endblock %}
```

app/console assets:install

Thats all

Pay attention to the correct filepath

Answer (score 1):

The [javascripts tag](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#including-javascript-files) has specific usage for referencing assets

```
{% javascripts filter="" output="js/core.js" debug=true
    "@InterempleaBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, still no results, what I did is to replace the code and run again  assets:install web [--symlink]. What seems a little weird is when I see root directory I can see a js void directory.

Comment: Oh, the `javascripts` tag works a little different. I have updated my answer